# What's the difference between echo $(filename) and cat filename?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, cat

```
echo $(cat filename)
```

and

```
cat filename
```

produce the same output for me. Why?

Comment: Try adding multiple whitespaces and newlines into your file, then try again. Also try leading and trailing newline and whitespace. Or try starting your file with "-n", "-e", or any other option-like string

Comment: Also, be aware of the difference between `echo $(cat filename)` and `echo "$(cat filename)"`

Comment: Your title asks a different question than the actual question.

Comment: @StevenLevnine : In addition to the correct answer given by ceving: If the last character of the file is not a newline, `echo ....` will add a newline in the output, but a mere `cat ....` won't.

Answer (score 2):

For the first you will get the ["useless use of echo award"](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#echo). For the second not.

> There is a twist: echo will "flatten" any whitespace in $variable into a single space -- unless you double-quote $variable, of course --, and sometimes you can legitimately use echo in backticks for this side effect. But that's rarely necessary or useful, and so most often, this is just a misguided use of echo.

So forget the first. Its broken.

Comment: Technically, it's a little more complicated, as the arguments that `echo` sees are determined by the value of `IFS`. `echo` itself writes those arguments separated by a single whitespace.